# How to print all the elements from a ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to print all the element I have added to my arraylist, but it only prints the adress and not the string.
Can someone help me or give out some tips? I've been searching all afternoon

Comment: You need to override `toString()` method in your Auteur class. If you have showed your Auteur class, we could have given sample toString of it.

Comment: Howcome? ArrayList :: toString returns a string representation of this collection in [] rit ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()

Answer (score 3):

You need to override Autuer's toString method to return its contents in String format

Answer (score 1):

You can also, use a foreach to do it ;)

```
for(Auteur a: auteurs){
    System.out.print(a.getName() + " - " + a.getNumber());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every object in Java inherits

```
public String toString();
```

from `java.lang.Object`

in your `Auteur` class you need to write some code similar to the following:

....
....

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name: "+this.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the `toString()` method in your `Auter` class as follows:

```
public String toString() {
    return this.getName() + " - " + this.getNumber());
}
```

and your code will do what you wish. `System.out.println` calls the argument's `toString()` method and prints that out to the Output console.

Answer (score 0):

`itr.next()` returns object of `Auteur` rather than `String`. To print the name you need to type cast it with `Auteur` and then print it if you have a print method for the class `Auteur`.

```
Auteur aut = (Auteur) itr.next();
System.out.println(aut.printMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see is called the default [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) of an object. It is an amalgamation of the FQCN (fully qualified class name) of the class it belongs to and the hashCode of the object.

Quoting from the JavaDoc of toString:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:
>
> ```
>  getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

We can override `toString` to give a more human readable output. Take a look at the below two classes, with and without `toString`. Try to execute the main method and compare the output of the two print statements.

```
class Person {
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + this.name + "]";
    }
}

class Address {
    private String town;
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        Address address = new Address();

        System.out.println("Person is : " + person);
        System.out.println("Address is : " + address);
    }
}
```